# Versioning of Angular node modules for publishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, bash, gitignore

While trying to publish Angular components on npm, I am not quite sure which folders and files should be included in the versioning process and which should be in the `.gitignore`.

I use the Angular CLI for publishing. The main code is in `./projects/nls-ngx-module/src/**` and for transpiling I use the native angular command `ng build --prod` from inside the project folder. Inside `dist/` a new folder arrives with the project title. Fine.

After transpiling, another `node_modules` folder is added to the project folder, which is not ignored by default. It only contains a `.cache` folder with subfolders and files. And that irritates me, because in other sample projects they do not appear, but they have not been ignored manually in the `.gitignore` either.

**Folder structure**

```
├── ...
├── projects
│   └── nls-ngx-module
│       ├── karma.conf.js
│       ├── ng-package.json
│       ├── ng-package.prod.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── lib
│       │   │   ├── ...
│       │   ├── public_api.ts
│       │   └── test.ts
│       ├── tsconfig.lib.json
│       ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│       └── tslint.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── assets
│   ├── browserslist
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
├── ...
```

**.gitignore**

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
testem.log
/typings
package-lock.json

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Examples taken from:

- [mrsan22/NgxMatTypeahead](https://github.com/mrsan22/NgxMatTypeahead/tree/master/projects/ngx-mat-typeahead)
- [faxemaxe/ngx-cli-lib-demo](https://github.com/faxemaxe/ngx-cli-lib-demo)

Answer (score 1):

No, no modification of the `.gitignore` file has to be done. The `ng build` command was executed in the wrong directory.

Do not run `ng build --prod` or any similiar `ng build` command **outside the root directory** of the application. The *node_modules* folder is only created inside the projects directory when you run the `ng build` command inside the subfolders of the *projects* diretory.

**Note**
The `ng build` command distributes all necessary dependencies listed inside the `package.json`. Therefore there has to be a *node_modules* folder to bundle the built library correctly.

Comment: Part of this answer is misleading. There are `ng` commands that can be run outside of the context of a project directory. `ng new`, `ng help`, `ng get/set` with the `--global` option, `ng version`, `ng doc`, and `ng completion` are all valid outside the application root.

Comment: @R.Richards You're right. I meant any `ng build` command with other parameters. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating! Always good to be clear with this stuff.